# Simplify the typescript interface for fetched data from api

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I want to fetch movie data from omdbapi.

I'm trying to embed typescript to determine the exact data I get from the endpoint (I'm new to typescript).

The structure of the obtained data looks something like this, is it really necessary to list all the data individually in the interface if it is a string?

```js
interface Movie {
  Title: string;
  Year: string;
  Rated: string;
  Released: string;
  Runtime: string;
  Genre: string;
  Director: string;
  Writer: string;
  Actors: string;
  Plot: string;
  Language: string;
  Country: string;
  Awards: string;
  Poster: string;
  Ratings: [
    {
      Source: string;
      Value: string;
    },
    {
      Source: string;
      Value: string;
    },
    {
      Source: string;
      Value: string;
    }
  ];
  Metascore: string;
  imdbRating: string;
  imdbVotes: string;
  imdbID: string;
  Type: string;
  DVD: string;
  BoxOffice: string;
  Production: string;
  Website: string;
  Response: string;
}
```

Comment: Just a question... Is `Ratings` really always a tuple of length 3, or is it an array of those objects?

Comment: You are right, this field is variable, it can have several objects or no object. Is it possible to adapt this to this case as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```
type Movie = Record<"Title" | "Year" | "... more keys here ..." | "Website" | "Response", string> & {
  Ratings: {
    Source: string;
    Value: string;
  }[];
};
```

Give it a union of all the keys that map to strings, and then intersect (combine) the record with an object type that holds the type for `Ratings`.

Comment: Great! Is the record commonly used? Or it is preferred to list all the items as I posted.

Comment: You've got a lot of properties here, so I think a `Record` would be preferable.